# [__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsarray

I want to save array of images into photo album. When i use single image for saving it works [UIImage imageNamed:"test.png"]. But if i use array of images i'm getting error'

```
NSArray *photos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpg"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"],
                       nil] ;


    for ( UIImage *imagesave in photos )

      //image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:image];

    [self.library saveImage:imagesave toAlbum:@"Art" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];
```

Comment: What is error description?

Comment: On which line you get that error? What kind of error is it - app crashes, you just get error message printed in console by your NSLog code?

Comment: 2014-06-11 16:03:08.517 Art[15392:907] -[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e8909e0
2014-06-11 16:03:08.521 Art[15392:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e8909e0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` is called from `for (... in ...)`. From the given code, are you sure that `photos` is survive till the end of the for loop? It seems like it was deallocated before it finished doing that.